# What is the proper way to reference a sibling module such as Diesel's generated schema?

Tags: module, rust, schema, rust-diesel

I'm building a web service that uses Diesel to access a MySQL database. Everything is setup correctly and Diesel is generating the `schema.rs` file with content that reflects my database schema:

```
table! {
    user (id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I created a `store.rs` file that resides next to `main.rs`. If my understanding of modules is correct, any code I put in the `store.rs` file, will belong to a module named `store` that is a child of the `crate` module. My intention is to put all the code that deals with database stuff in the `store` module. However, I can't seem to be able to `use` the stuff from the `schema` module in my `store` module to start doing some querying using the Diesel APIs.

I tried:

- `use schema;`
- `use crate::schema;`
- `use super::schema;`
- `use super::schema::user;`

Nothing works. The compiler always says that it cannot resolve one piece of the path or another.

What is the proper way to reference a sibling module in Rust?

Comment: Do you have a `pub mod schema` statement in `main.rs`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help.

in store.rs

```
use crate::schema::*;

// … any other diesel related code you want to put here
```

in main.rs

```
pub mod schema;
mod store;
```

Comment: `schema.rs` is an autogenerated file by Diesel. I don't think you're supposed to be changing it.

Comment: I am also new to rust. Sorry, if it is misleading or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your main.rs, make sure you're setting diesel for #[macro_use] and importing the schema mod.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
mod schema;
```

In store.rs, you should be able to use the schema as you see fit.

```
use crate::schema::user;
```